# How to check the status of a database field changed after 3 days of its creation with php and mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, notifications

I am making an online shopping cart but I want to be sure that the products that you select are reserved for 3 days and when the time is up, return the total of products that the customer booked and update the status of the shopping cart, or also if it has generated A comment the admin receives a notice on your page as on facebook as when they like like one of your photos notifies you

how I can do it, I had thought of a trigger but how can I go back to the background or what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Don't ask two questions in one post. It might be closed as "too broad". However for the first part, you can just add a column `expires_at TIMESTAMP` to your `cart` table.

Answer (score 0):

There are about a million ways (okay, maybe tens) to solve this problem. For example, you can have a cron job that runs once an hour or whatever time period works for you. The job runs your PHP program and performs the actions that you want for out-of-date entries. Simply select the items that meet your criteria, remove them from the cart, and then notify the user in whatever way you want.